# How to instantiate multiple jQuery File Uploads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

So basically, I am having a hard time trying to create multiple [jQuery File Uploads](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

Currently, I have a button on my page that allows a user to create a new `div` that contains text inputs and a few graphs. I would like to add a file upload part to of these new `div`s they create so that they can attach images. The number of new `div`s that can create is unlimited. The divs are created from a long Javascript string and appended to the end of a container.

I would like to use the 'Basic Plus UI' version since it has a better and cleaner interface.

Some very basic instructions are displayed on the site on how to have [multiple file upload widgets on the same page](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Multiple-File-Upload-Widgets-on-the-same-page), although I am not to sure if this is possible or not with dynamic creation.

**The main problems I am facing:** The uploader appends the selected images with their information to a section below it. My code would have to work with `$(this)` to make sure that each uploader is completely separate from the others. The plugin currently works with IDs and not classes, so I would have to find away around this also.

Of course, I am not asking anyone to write a ton of code for me! Just some guideance on how to approach this would be great.

Comment: First of all I would suggest you try to re-structure your app to have different forms for each of the newly added divs by removing the parent form. Or use iframe for new divs. Also, can you please post jsfiddle to show exact problem as it is hard to understand the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the advice @amitamb - Literally around 5 minutes before you posted that, I changed the structure completely. Many elements within my page did not require a `form`, so I wrapped them in a `div` instead so that each individual file uploader can now be wrapped in a `form`.

Comment: Might be obvious to you, but I could not make sense of this without an example: "My code would have to work with $(this) to make sure that each uploader is completely separate from the others. The plugin currently works with IDs and not classes, so I would have to find away around this also."

Comment: Sorry @amitamb, after reading it a few times over I figured that it may be impossible for other people to understand. The code that I would have to write would have to separate all file uploads from eachother. I attempted doing this myself, and when I uploaded an image into one uploader, it was also uploaded and displayed in the other uploader. This happended because I was not using the jQuery `$(this)` selector.

Answer (score 1):

As i know, with dynamically created objects you should work through `$(selector).on(..`

As example:

```
$('.parent_container').on('click', '.btn', function(){
// do something
})
```

or `live(..)` instead `on(..)` in old versions of JQuery

You can more read about it here:
https://api.jquery.com/on/

It should help . . .